# API JSON Response - Empty Page

Tags: php, mysql, json, api

This is my DB Structure and DB Data

[DB Strcture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/osAfV.png)

[DB Data](https://justpaste.it/4dij8)

This is my API

```
<?php
include("baseconfig/db_conection.php");
if(!empty($_GET['search']) && !empty($_GET['count']))
{
    $search=$_GET['search'];
    $count=$_GET['count'];
    if(strcasecmp((substr("$count", -1)),'S') == 0)
    {
        $num=explode('s', $count);
        $number=$num[0];
        if(strcasecmp($search, 'ALL') == 0 && is_numeric($number))
        {
            $query="SELECT * FROM `brandnew` WHERE smokeunit=$number AND smoketype='Cigratte' ORDER BY smokename ASC";
        }
        else if(strcasecmp($search, 'A-D') == 0 && is_numeric($number))
        {
            $query="SELECT * FROM `brandnew` WHERE smokename REGEXP '^[A-D].*$' AND smokeunit=$number AND smoketype='Cigratte' ORDER BY smokename ASC";
        }
        else if(strcasecmp($search, 'E-I') == 0 && is_numeric($number))
        {
            $query="SELECT * FROM `brandnew` WHERE smokename REGEXP '^[E-I].*$' AND smokeunit=$number AND smoketype='Cigratte' ORDER BY smokename ASC";
        }
        else if(strcasecmp($search, 'J-O') == 0 && is_numeric($number))
        {
            $query="SELECT * FROM `brandnew` WHERE smokename REGEXP '^[J-O].*$' AND smokeunit=$number AND smoketype='Cigratte' ORDER BY smokename ASC";
        }
        else if(strcasecmp($search, 'P-T') == 0 && is_numeric($number))
        {
            $query="SELECT * FROM `brandnew` WHERE smokename REGEXP '^[P-T].*$' AND smokeunit=$number AND smoketype='Cigratte' ORDER BY smokename ASC";
        }
        else if(strcasecmp($search, 'U-Z') == 0 && is_numeric($number))
        {
            $query="SELECT * FROM `brandnew` WHERE smokename REGEXP '^[U-Z].*$' AND smokeunit=$number AND smoketype='Cigratte' ORDER BY smokename ASC";
        }
        else
        {
            $query="SELECT * FROM `brandnew` ORDER BY smokename ASC";
        }
    }
    else if(strcasecmp((substr("$count", -1)),'G') == 0)
    {
        $num=explode('g', $count);
        $number=$num[0];
        if(strcasecmp($search, 'ALL') == 0 && is_numeric($number))
        {
            $query="SELECT * FROM `brandnew` WHERE smokeunit=$number AND smoketype='Tobacco' ORDER BY smokename ASC";
        }
        else if(strcasecmp($search, 'A-D') == 0 && is_numeric($number))
        {
            $query="SELECT * FROM `brandnew` WHERE smokename REGEXP '^[A-D].*$' AND smokeunit=$number AND smoketype='Tobacco' ORDER BY smokename ASC";
        }
        else if(strcasecmp($search, 'E-I') == 0 && is_numeric($number))
        {
            $query="SELECT * FROM `brandnew` WHERE smokename REGEXP '^[E-I].*$' AND smokeunit=$number AND smoketype='Tobacco' ORDER BY smokename ASC";
        }
        else if(strcasecmp($search, 'J-O') == 0 && is_numeric($number))
        {
            $query="SELECT * FROM `brandnew` WHERE smokename REGEXP '^[J-O].*$' AND smokeunit=$number AND smoketype='Tobacco' ORDER BY smokename ASC";
        }
        else if(strcasecmp($search, 'P-T') == 0 && is_numeric($number))
        {
            $query="SELECT * FROM `brandnew` WHERE smokename REGEXP '^[P-T].*$' AND smokeunit=$number AND smoketype='Tobacco' ORDER BY smokename ASC";
        }
        else if(strcasecmp($search, 'U-Z') == 0 && is_numeric($number))
        {
            $query="SELECT * FROM `brandnew` WHERE smokename REGEXP '^[U-Z].*$' AND smokeunit=$number AND smoketype='Tobacco' ORDER BY smokename ASC";
        }
        else
        {
            $query="SELECT * FROM `brandnew` ORDER BY smokename ASC";
        }
    }
}
else if(!empty($_GET['search']))
{
    $search=$_GET['search'];
    if(strcasecmp($search, 'ALL') == 0)
    {
        $query="SELECT * FROM `brandnew` ORDER BY smokename ASC";
    }
    else if(strcasecmp($search, 'A-D') == 0)
    {
        $query="SELECT * FROM `brandnew` WHERE smokename REGEXP '^[A-D].*$' ORDER BY smokename ASC";
    }
    else if(strcasecmp($search, 'E-I') == 0)
    {
        $query="SELECT * FROM `brandnew` WHERE smokename REGEXP '^[E-I].*$' ORDER BY smokename ASC";
    }
    else if(strcasecmp($search, 'J-O') == 0)
    {
        $query="SELECT * FROM `brandnew` WHERE smokename REGEXP '^[J-O].*$' ORDER BY smokename ASC";
    }
    else if(strcasecmp($search, 'P-T') == 0)
    {
        $query="SELECT * FROM `brandnew` WHERE smokename REGEXP '^[P-T].*$' ORDER BY smokename ASC";
    }
    else if(strcasecmp($search, 'U-Z') == 0)
    {
        $query="SELECT * FROM `brandnew` WHERE smokename REGEXP '^[U-Z].*$' ORDER BY smokename ASC";
    }
}
else if(!empty($_GET['count']))
{
    $count=$_GET['count'];
    if(strcasecmp((substr("$count", -1)),'S') == 0)
    {
        $num=explode('s', $count);
        $number=$num[0];
        if(is_numeric($number))
        {
            $query="SELECT * FROM `brandnew` WHERE smokeunit=$number AND smoketype='Cigratte' ORDER BY smokename ASC";
        }
    }
    else if(strcasecmp((substr("$count", -1)),'G') == 0)
    {
        $num=explode('g', $count);
        $number=$num[0];
        if(is_numeric($number))
        {
            $query="SELECT * FROM `brandnew` WHERE smokeunit=$number AND smoketype='Tobacco' ORDER BY smokename ASC";
        }
    }
}
else if(empty($_GET['search']) && empty($_GET['count']))
{
    $query="SELECT * FROM `brandnew` ORDER BY smokename ASC";
}
$run=mysqli_query($dbcon,$query);
$result=mysqli_affected_rows($dbcon);
$id=new \stdClass();
if($run && $result > 0)
{
    while($row=mysqli_fetch_assoc($run))
    {
        $id->success='Yes';
        $id->smoke[]=$row;
    }
}
else if($run)
{
    $id->success='Yes';
    $id->smoke=NULL;
}
else
{
    $id->success='No';
}
$myJSON=json_encode($id);
echo $myJSON;
?>
```

So, the problem comes when I try to query the API using the following parameters

```
localhost/smoke/api/allcallserviceapinew.php
localhost/smokes/api/allcallserviceapinew.php?search=all&count=all
localhost/smokes/api/allcallserviceapinew.php?search=all&count=20s
localhost/smokes/api/allcallserviceapinew.php?search=all&count=25g
```

I get an empty page response. Previously I had this issue and hence converted all fields to utf8_bin format as in pic, but still no response.

[No Response](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AtDdZ.png)

And also especially to the query P-T category.

I am also able to get the output for

```
localhost/smokes/api/allcallserviceapinew.php?search=A-D&count=20s
localhost/smokes/api/allcallserviceapinew.php?search=E-I&count=20s
localhost/smokes/api/allcallserviceapinew.php?search=J-O&count=25g
```

[Output for other Category](https://i.stack.imgur.com/54MKu.png)

I am in a total lost, whether the query is going wrong or where the data is corrupted. Can anyone provide some information, where things are going wrong?

Thanks

Comment: Do you have `display_errors` on? As you're getting no output at all, it's likely there's a fatal error somewhere.

Comment: display_errors is turned on in php.ini file. The same api works well for other characters like A-D, E-I and all but not only for P-I and I suspect that is what is blocking my other JSON output too

Comment: I've made a local copy of your database on my server running PHP7 and MySQL 5.6 and your code works fine except for the `search=all&count=all` case, where you are missing a condition in your if/else structure to deal with that (I changed `if(strcasecmp((substr("$count", -1)),'S') == 0)` to `if(strcasecmp((substr("$count", -1)),'S') == 0 || strcasecmp($count, 'ALL') == 0)` to make that work),

Comment: Hi Nick, Thanks for that. Actually I updated my code and added a complete if condition for it 

else if(strcasecmp($search, 'ALL') == 0 && strcasecmp($search, 'ALL') == 0)
        {
            $query="SELECT * FROM `brand` ORDER BY smokename ASC";
        }

That part is working fine. But I am still stuck for the P-T request